# VB.NET dynamical dead code analysis

Tags: vb.net

favorite
I have a VB.NET library which is heavily used in very much projects (some of them are not really known and not in our hands) in a huge enterprise environment on high traffic.

We want to decommission this library. For this, I search for a good tool for a dynamic code analysis, which means, that I want to find the unused code while the using projects are running. We planning to run such an analysis for some month on all projects, before we start decommission the library partly.

We can only change this VB.NET dll!

We have a Splunk server where we maybe can collect the usage data. Or we can provide another server for data collection. Important is that this collection of usage data needs to be fast, as long as we are in a very high traffic environment. Out of this dll there in average something around 400,000 API calls per hour, or maybe more. It's hard to figure that out. How many pure business logic methods are used from the library is unknown.